# Usar el web api de una aplicacion blazor-wasm en aplicación de escritorio

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, blazor, wasm

Necesito hacer dos aplicaciones:

- Una parte en blazor-wasm que gestione unos datos vía web.
- Una parte en c# para escritorio que acceda a los mismos datos.

No quiero duplicar código por lo que había pensado usar parte de los servicio web-api de blazor para acceder desde la aplicación de escritorio.

Esto es posible?

He probado acceder a un servicio de otra aplicacion blazor-wasm y me dice que no es posible y lo que no se es si hay que configurar algo dentro de la app blazor. Tengo esta api:

```
namespace Apliacion.Server.Controllers
    {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EspaciosController : ControllerBase
      {
      private readonly J2GestionCasaMadreContext _context;

      public EspaciosController(J2GestionCasaMadreContext context)
        {
        _context = context;
        }

      // GET: api/Espacios
      [HttpGet]
      public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<EspacioViewModel>>> GetEspacios()
        {
      List<Espacio> espacios =await _context.Espacios.OrderBy(o=>o.NombreEspacio).ToListAsync();
      return Ok(espacios);
      }
    }
  }
```

Y funciona perfectamente dentro del blazor:

```
protected async Task CargaEspcacios()
    {
    estado = "Cargando datos";
    try
        {
        espacios = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<EspacioViewModel>>("/api/Espacios");
        estado = "";
        }
    catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
        {
        estado = "Error.";
        exception.Redirect();
        }
    }
```

Obtengo un listado de espacios, pero si abro un navegador y pongo **https://www.miblazor.com/api/Espacios** obtengo un error **Sorry, there's nothing at this address.**

Gracias

Comment: La direccion es la que probaste realmente?? o es un ejemplo? si tu api es publica, deberias poder acceder.. el tema es que este bien la direccion...

Comment: la dirección es un ejemplo. Si estoy depurando la aplicación en mi equipo si puede acceder con https://localhost:34345/api/Espacios, pero en modo producción, accediendo al servidor, nada  de nada

Comment: Acabo de probar una cosa, super extraña.  Si abro el Edge y he intento acceder a la pagina https://www.miblazor.com/api/Espacios no va, pero si depuro la aplicación, abro una pestaña nueva en el navegador que lanza el Visual Studio y pongo la misma dirección si que funciona. muy extraño

Comment: no entiendo tu ultimo comentario.. no va, cuando no se esta ejecutando??? y si va cuando se esta ejecutando??? algo no me cuadra...

Comment: Yo abro el navegador y pongo https://miblazor.com/api/Espacios y da error. Ahora abro la aplicación el visual studio, le doy depurar, me abre un navegador, en este navegador que se ha abierto abro una pestaña, pongo en la barra de direcciones exactamente https://miblazor.com/api/Espacios (es decir, lo mismo) y funciona

Comment: si pero.. cuando la abres por primera vez, porque esperas que alguien conteste?? esta prendida en algun lado???

Comment: vos me estas diciendo que apagada no funciona (lo cual es obvio) y que prendida si.. algo no suena bien...

Comment: A ver, la aplicación está publica en internet y funciona bien, pero solo acceder a los webapi desde el navegador que lanza Visual Studio

Comment: que la app este publica, no quiere decir que la api este publica.. aca ya me excede a si cuando haces una app blazor, el back queda publico o no... tu pregunta es como hacer publica el back de una app blazor... yo, no lo se...

Comment: Para que funcione en blazor la API tiene que ser visible dentro de la red, ya sea internet, intranet o VPN. Una API para blazor no tiene nada de especial, por lo que cualquier otro programa (incluido uno de escritorio) es capaz de leerlo. De los comentarios entiendo que tu problema es que a la hora de publicarlo da problemas. Si funciona desde VS y no desde producción, es un tema de configuración. Revisa el event viewer

Comment: Mas que a la hora de publicarlo, es que no puedo acceder a la API desde fuera de la aplicación de Blazor, porque la aplicación si que funciona, esa API y 10 mas que tiene la aplicación, pero desde fuera da error. Mirarle lo que dices

Comment: Pudiera ser porque en el appsetting.json  del  server tengo esto?"IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "ServerXXXX.Client": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    }
  },